# HttpUrlConnection: How to know if connection started downloading or uploading?

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection, android-networking, android-internet

In my Android app, I would like to change the icon in the notification bar to be different when the connection is uploading versus downloading.

How can I intercept sending/receiving data in order to update the notification? I am using HttpUrlConnection APIs.